# How to use Mysql Workbench to figure out why scripts are so slow?

Tags: nginx, mysql

I have a laragon environment on a fairly decent machine:
[image]

I have a simple hard coded web application (no frameworks), with a Bootstrap4+jQuery front-end.

On page load, it does a few very simple and low stress mySQL selects.

However, even when running things completely local, the pages are displaying very sluggishly with over 2 seconds load time.

I did some basic tests and script time tracing and found that the PHP Code and even HTML/JS renderings are quite fast, but if a page involves an SQL request that's when things really lag to 2 seconds or more.

So I believe this for now eliminates any issues with other parts of the web application, Laragon, or even the host machine (ram, antivirus, etc)

I installed MYSQL workbench to try and figure things out but alas, im not good with server administration stuff.

Given the above scenario I have explained, what should I look for or test in mysql workbench in order to figure this out?

Comment: Try JetProfiler.com for a quick non-invasive utility that will find Top Queries, Top Tables simply by connecting to your MySQL instance.  Default polling interval is 1 second, change to 10 seconds if your server is very busy and still find in Top Queries the query that needs help.  EXPLAIN click is built in. There is a FREE trial for as long as you want to use it. Let me know if it helps you and your team, please.

Comment: Provide the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, then go to stackoverflow.com , where lots of folks can help you.